# PHP Long post variable cutting off when assigning to a php variable

Tags: php, json, post

I am using a post variable to push Json data to my site. Everything is working for small Json string lengths but when the string is longer it is getting cutoff when I assign it to a php variable. The test code looks something like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){


    $size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
    $tempJson = stripcslashes($_POST['data']);

    $tmpData = json_decode($tempJson, true);
//functions to deal with the Json
    echo($size."  :   ");
    echo(strlen($_POST['data']));
}
```

This returns 44743  :  11267.

I checked the Json length on the requesting system and it matches at 44743.

I thought maybe it was an issue with the php.ini settings. So I adjusted the settings using a phprc file (Dreamhost).

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 105M
max_execution_size = 1500
max_input_time = 500
memory_limit = 256M
```

phpinfo(); confirms the settings change but I'm still having the same issues. 
Any thoughts on what else could be the cause?

Comment: are you sure that you  sand only one parameter with name data?

Comment: `$_SERVER["Content-Length"]` will provide the size of the entire request. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show you?

Comment: I managed to figure it out using Postman to review the headers. It was a logic issue with a error / return message tracking system that was overloading the ram. After I removed the system, things seem to be working fine.